# Pull mysql rows with max value of specific column in group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables as shown below :

```
            Table Name : scores
+-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| UNID  |   name    |    score     |   PRID    |
+-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|  1    |  name_1   |      93      |        1  |
|  2    |  name_2   |      71      |        1  |
|  3    |  name_3   |      53      |        2  |
|  4    |  name_4   |      82      |        2  |
|  5    |  name_5   |      31      |        2  |
|  6    |  name_6   |      68      |        3  |
+-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

And

```
                  Table Name : user_dir
+-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| PRID  |   fname   |    city      |   gender  |
+-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|  1    |  fname1   |      XX      |        m  |
|  2    |  fname2   |      YY      |        f  |
|  3    |  fname3   |      ZZ      |        f  |
+-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

For any given **PRID** from **user_dir**, how can I get the entire row that corresponds to the highest value of **score** for that **PRID**?

As an example, for the user "fname2" with a PRID of 2, I want to pull this entire row (and not just the value of **score**) as follows :

```
 +-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
 | UNID  |   name    |    score     |   PRID    |
 +-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
 |  4    |  name_4   |      82      |        2  |
```

I tried this using the "max" function of that row, but it instead gives me the **first row found with that PRID**, along with the correct (max) value of score, as follows :

```
 +-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
 | UNID  |   name    |    score     |   PRID    |
 +-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
 |  3    |  name_3   |      82      |        2  |
```

EDIT : **I misunderstood my requirement**, the final result needed to have the corresponding "name" value for the highest score, not the highest score itself.

So the actual final result would be :

```
+-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| PRID  |   name    |    fname     |   score   |
+-------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|  1    |  fname1   |    name_1    |     93    |
|  2    |  fname2   |    name_4    |     82    |
|  3    |  fname3   |    name_6    |     68    |
```

Comment: This question has been answered hundreds of times on Stack Overflow. I picked one of the oldest, highest-voted answers and voted to close this as a duplicate. If you don't like that one, click the tag I added and find one of the many other answers.

Comment: @BillKarwin The duplicate you linked to is for Oracle. It won't work in MySQL.

Comment: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.*
FROM scores s
WHERE PRID = 2 AND score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM scores WHERE PRID = 2)
```

If you wanted to obtain records containing all highest scores for each `PRID`, then you can try the following:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM scores s
WHERE score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM scores s1 WHERE s.PRID = s1.PRID)
```